# ls - ltr error because nothing in folder

Tags: bash, ls

I have a script and in the script I am running the below command.

```
ls -1tr ${ARCH1_DIR}/* | grep ${LOG_PREFIX} > $copied_binlog_set
```

if the folder is empty I get an error.

> ls: cannot access /n01/mysqlarch1/*: No such file or directory

The script at this point stops processing.  Is there a way so the script can carry on processing if the folder is empty.

Comment: I'm confused by your choice of accepted answer. If this question is solely about *suppressing* the error message, you could've said so. Because, your script *does* carry on processing even if a command in the script fails. You are aware of this, I hope? *A script does not automatically abort if an error occurs.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
ls -1tr ${ARCH1_DIR}/* 2>/dev/null | grep ${LOG_PREFIX} > $copied_binlog_set
```

When you write `2> file`, it redirect stderr to `file`, but you can use the `null` device and throws the input it gets. You can think about it as the black hole of your system.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` is expanded by the shell, not the `ls` command. This means, if there is no file, the shell does not expand the `*`, and `ls` tries to display the listing for a file *named* `*` in the target directory -- which is not there, hence the error.

You can redirect the error message (`ls ... 2>/dev/null`), and catch the error condition via the bash variable `PIPESTATUS`:

```
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} != 0 ]
then
    # whatever error handling your script needs at this point
    echo "ls failed!"
fi
```

`PIPESTATUS` allows to retrieve the return value (`$?`) of any command in a pipe chain. (`$?` would only return the value of the *last* command in the chain). The index into the `PIPESTATUS` array is the index of the command in the pipe chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the directory name without the trailing `/*` to `ls`, and that will show its contents - or nothing if empty.

Your next problem then would be that `grep` would return a nonzero exit code if it doesn't find anything, and the solution to that is to use `awk` instead - which returns `0` even if it doesn't find any matches:

```sh
ls -1tr ${ARCH1_DIR} | awk '/${LOG_PREFIX}/' > $copied_binlog_set
```